# How can I rationalise a few numbers to restrict their sum to a particular value in excel?

Tags: summation

For example: i have the following numbers whose sum is 46.

1. 5
2. 3
3. 4
4. 4
5. 30

I need their sum to be restricted to 40. I need to now rationalise/ normalise the set of 5 numbers so that their sum does not exceed 40. Can you help me with a formula that would enable me to do this calculation in excel?

Comment: There are many ways you could adjust the numbers so that there sum is 40.  A trivial one would be to change the first number to 40 and the other 4 to zero; or make them all 8.

 Perhaps you can clarify what it is you really want and let us know if you have tried anything

Comment: 'Rationalise' may not be the correct word for this.

Comment: I need there to be logic to this. As this needs to be done for a large dataset. The goal is to normalise the working hours of an employee to 40 hours in a week.

Comment: This is too vague.  What rules need to be followed?  What properties do you want your "normalization" to have?  For instance...you could just multiply each number by $\frac {40}{46}$.  Does that work?  Why not?